# navbar active tab using using nuxt/vue

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxtjs

I have a side navbar and I'm trying to make it active according to page click.

This is my sidenav.nav which is a component.

```
<template>
  <aside class="col-md-3">
    <nav class="list-group">
      <a href="/" class="list-group-item" exact>
        Account overview
      </a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="/profile/address"> My Address </a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="/profile/orders"> My Orders </a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="/profile/wishlist"> My wishlist </a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="/profile/settings"> Settings </a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href=""> Log out </a>
    </nav>
  </aside>
</template>
```

Below is my code for address page, other pages are similar to this.

```
<template>
  <section class="section-content padding-y">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <sidenav />
        <!-- col.// -->
        <main class="col-md-9">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-light mb-3">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add new address
          </a>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <article class="box mb-4">
                <h6>London, United Kingdom</h6>
                <p>
                  Building: Nestone <br />
                  Floor: 22, Aprt: 12
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light disabled">
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Default</a
                >
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">
                  <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">
                  <i class="text-danger fa fa-trash"></i>
                </a>
              </article>
            </div>
            <!-- col.// -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <article class="box mb-4">
                <h6>Tashkent, Uzbekistan</h6>
                <p>
                  Building one <br />
                  Floor: 2, Aprt: 32
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Make default</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">
                  <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">
                  <i class="text-danger fa fa-trash"></i>
                </a>
              </article>
            </div>
            <!-- col.// -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <article class="box mb-4">
                <h6>Moscow, Russia</h6>
                <p>
                  Lenin street <br />
                  Building A, Floor: 3, Aprt: 32
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Make default</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">
                  <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">
                  <i class="text-danger fa fa-trash"></i>
                </a>
              </article>
            </div>
            <!-- col.// -->
          </div>
          <!-- row.// -->
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import sidenav from "~/components/profile-sidenav";
export default {
  components: {
    sidenav,
  },
};
</script>
```

I have set account overview as the active page, when i go to address page i need 'My address' tab to be active. How do i do that? I tried  but that didn't work.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes but not the vue-bootstrap. I'm using the cdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<a>` tags, use `<nuxt-link>`. Then, in your css, style the `.nuxt-link-exact-active` class— for example:

```
.nuxt-link-exact-active {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now if you have `<nuxt-link to=“/address”>My Address</nuxt-link>` and the user is on the /address page, the class is added to the nuxt-link element.